# read contacts primary screen shown(open from) is supernumerary

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts

I'm writing an app that get contacts and all detail , such as any numbers in each contact. it works fine but i have a problem. as you see in below images when I call:

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);        intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

first of all I see the (open from) screen like this:

[image: first screen]

and when i select " Contacts " the second screen is shown:

[image: second screen]

Is there any way that I call the the method, the second screen with contacts and detail numbers directly shown and i needless to see the first screen and select " Contacts ".
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After all I found this way:
instead of:

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);

I have write these lines:

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,Uri.parse("content://contacts/people"));             intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. Finally, I got rid of intermediate picker screen using below code,

```
Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
i.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
startActivityForResult(i, SELECT_PHONE_NUMBER);
```

In `onActivityResult` get phone number as below

```
if (requestCode == SELECT_PHONE_NUMBER && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
  // Get the URI and query the content provider for the phone number
  Uri contactUri = data.getData();
  String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};
  Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(contactUri, projection,
      null, null, null);

  // If the cursor returned is valid, get the phone number
  if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    int numberIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
    String number = cursor.getString(numberIndex);
    // Do something with the phone number
    ... 
  } 

  cursor.close();
}
```